# Significato di parametro in contesto

Tags: word-meaning

Buongiorno,

In inglese *parameter* è semplicemente un parametro o una variabile, visto anche da un punto di vista matematico o della teoria dei giochi.

Ma ho qualche difficoltà a valutare il significato di parametro nella seguente frase.

> Inoltre è necessario anche capire quali siano i parametri per valutare il concetto di "beneficio" in modo sufficientemente ampio.

Come si può valutare, magari anche magneticamente, un concetto di beneficio, in base a uno o più parametri?

Grazie per gli esempi e per le spiegazioni.

Comment: Non ho capito che cosa c'entra “magneticamente”...

Comment: A parte il magnetismo, per l'esempio specifico bisognerebbe sapere di che cosa si sta parlando. Comunque ti è chiaro che cosa vuol dire che qualcosa viene valutato in base a certi parametri, no? I parametri per valutare certe merci potrebbero essere per esempio il prezzo, la qualità, l'assistenza garantita dal produttore etc. “Parametro” non indica solo una variabile numerica o con valori ben definiti, ma più in generale un [criterio di giudizio](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/parametro).

Comment: Wordreference it-en conferma questo secondo uso di [parametro](https://www.wordreference.com/iten/parametro) e ne fornisce alcune traduzioni: *standard, yardstick, parameter, guideline, criterion*.

Answer (score 4):

In questo caso l'accezione matematica non va considerata. Secondo il [dizionario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/parametro/), l'accezione 2 indica

> Nel linguaggio comune, in senso figurato, unità di misura, criterio di giudizio, e simili: *ognuno giudica la situazione secondo parametri diversi*.

L'etimologia è dal francese, *para* e *mètre*, cioè “simile a una (unità di) misura”.